# sencha touch 2.0 numberfield formating only in ios

Tags: sencha-touch-2

When i enter big number in numberfield and blur it add coma in beetween number only in IOS,
I want to remove this functionallity.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just dealt with this issue.  Unfortunately numberfield has HTML5 specs that suggest putting a comma in place by default.  There is no way around this on iOS that I have found.

My solution was to use a 'textfield' component and strip out all non number chars with a regular expression 'onblur'.

Alternatively, if all you need are the base numbers, you could always use a 'textfield' and set its type to 'tel' which will give you a telephone keypad on mobile phones.

Hope this helps.

Code Examples:

Texfield component that strips all non number characters.  This would be inside a view.  You could also listen for the blur even inside a controller using the 'control' config object:

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    ui: 'plain',
    listeners: {
        //  listen for blur event
        blur: function(field){
            var val = field.getValue(); // store a ref to our field's value
            val = val.replace(/[^\d]*/g, ""); // strip non-digit characters
            field.setValue(val); // update our field value
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of setting the type to tel:

```
{
    xtype     : 'textfield',
    label     : 'Phone Number',
    component : {
        type : 'tel'
    }
}
```